# How to impute missing rows with mean in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with datetimes separated by 1 hour as indexes. However, sometimes a row is missing. Something like the example below, where there is no row for the datetime `2019-01-01 04:00:00`:

```
                             price_eur
datetime                         
2019-01-01 00:00:00          51.0
2019-01-01 01:00:00          46.27
2019-01-01 02:00:00          39.78
2019-01-01 03:00:00          20.0
2019-01-01 05:00:00          22.0
```

I want to impute the missing rows by taking the average of the elements of the rows immediately surrounding the missing one, i.e. I want to obtain the following dataframe:

```
                             price_eur
datetime                         
2019-01-01 00:00:00          51.0
2019-01-01 01:00:00          46.27
2019-01-01 02:00:00          39.78
2019-01-01 03:00:00          20.0
2019-01-01 04:00:00          21.0
2019-01-01 05:00:00          22.0
```

I know that I could use the resample method to impute the missing value either with the value preceding the missing one or the value following it, like so,

```
prices_df.resample('1H').fillna('pad',limit=1)
```

but I'm not sure how to impute with the mean. Can anybody help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`.interpolate()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.interpolate.html)

```
df.asfreq('1h').interpolate()
```

```
                     price_eur
datetime                      
2023-05-31 00:00:00      51.00
2023-05-31 01:00:00      46.27
2023-05-31 02:00:00      39.78
2023-05-31 03:00:00      20.00
2023-05-31 04:00:00      21.00
2023-05-31 05:00:00      22.00
```

Comment: Nice and simple! Thanks :)